# How do I use the Windows Voice recognition in a Delphi Application?

Tags: windows, delphi, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I know how to make the application read text and say things using VBScript files in Delphi, but I would please like to know how can I let the application listen to commands and respond to it. Like an Artificial Intelligent system which can use the basic windows commands, but from my Delphi application instead of the original Windows Voice Recognition.

Comment: You start with a websearch and read some documentation. For instance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx). If you can do what you want with VBscript then you can use the same COM API from Delphi. Do you know how to use COM in Delphi? Perhaps that's all you need.

Comment: No, i do not know how to use it. I am new in Delphi. I only know basics about VBScript as well. I started programming in Delphi about a year ago.

Comment: I know how to use a VBScript file like:    Var
       VBScript : textfile;
    begin
         AssignFile(VBScript,'VBScript.vbs');
         Rewrite(VBScript);
         CloseFile(VBScript); //This is easy

Comment: Writing a text file is easy. I'm assuming that you know how to do that. The contents of the vbscript presumably matter. Anyway, you should start by doing some research. At the moment I'm not even sure whether or not you have any meaningful vbscript. I've no idea whether you know which API you want to use. Whether you know anything about Delphi. Whether you know how to use COM. Whether you know about early bound and late bound. Whether or not that matters. Whether you need TTS or STT or both. You question is massively broad and it's not clear whether you have any idea how to tackle it.

Comment: I know a lot about Delphi, I have completed learning the Creative Programming in Delphi (PArt 1+2) books and I know everything they learned me. I have a few VBScript knowledge, like creating variables and how to let the computer read text and things like that, what I do not know is how to let it use the Windows Speech Recognition and how that works. I couldn't really find anything like that on the internet when I searched for it.

Comment: I'm struggling to see where vbscript comes into this then. Why is the question tagged Delphi if you want to use vbscript?

Comment: I want to do it in Delphi and I know it is possible to do it with VBScript in Delphi: Var
   VBScript : textfile;
   Text_To_Read : string;
begin
     AssignFile(VBScript,'PC Talk.vbs');
     Rewrite(VBScript,'PC Talk.vbs');
     Text_To_Read := 'Dim mgs, sapi';
     Writeln(VBScript,Text_To_Read);
     Text_To_Read := 'mgs = "' + Edit1.Text + '"';
     Writeln(VBScript,Text_To_Read);
     Text_To_Read := 'Set sapi = CreateObject("Sapi.SPVoice")';
     Writeln(VBScript,Text_To_Read);
     Text_To_Read := 'Sapi.Speak mgs';
     Writeln(VBScript,Text_To_Read);
     CloseFile(VBScript);
end;

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help like this. If you want to show vbscript, please don't show it indirectly via Delphi code to write a text file containing vbscript! Please don't add information in comments. If you want to show vbscript, show it in the question.

Comment: I needed to write VBScript via Delphi. I didnt want to show the code in Question, I just showed in in Comments so that you can see that I am using Delphi Code to write VBScript.

Answer (score 6):

You can do everything in Delphi without resorting to any VBScript at all.

Firstly, I'd recommend you read up on the concepts and gain yourself a good grounding in the principles. Once you have a good understanding of the concepts you can utilise the Microsoft Speech API component by importing its Type Library into your project.

Brian Long wrote an excellent article on the speech API which is available with source code on EDN and can be found [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29583)

Comment: Thanks I will read it later and come back to this discussion and say again whether I need help more and with what

Comment: Thanks, I like that website. It will really help me a lot